# Visual Studio 2017: Ruleset won't execute

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I want to define a custom set of rules to be checked at compile time. But it seems not to work.

Example:
I choose one rule directly and I'll get the expected warning.
[image]

But when I instead create a custom ruleset containing the exact same rule then I won't get the expected warning.
[image]

What could be wrong?

Edit:

```
void f(std::string& i) {
    std::string s = i;
    cout << s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s ("abc");
    f(s);
}
```

This gives me the expected warning **Warnung    C26460  The reference argument 'i' for function 'f' can be marked as const (con.3).** in the first case.
Even if I create a custom ruleset including all available rules, I won't get any warnings.

Here you see me selecting the custom ruleset:
[image]

Edit: The ruleset action must change one time to enable it.
When I create a new ruleset containing only the const-checks then I will get a .ruleset that does not work and look like this:
[image]
In the ruleset editor it looks like this:
[image]
When I then change its action from Warning to Error:
[image]
Then the .ruleset gets additional lines for each test case:
[image]
When I change the action back to warning it looks like this:
[image]
Now it is working as expected.

Comment: Can you provide more info? What would be the expected output and what is it that you are getting? What is the default rule code set and which one are you changing it for?

Comment: Are you sure you're applying your custom rule set, apart from just creating it?

Comment: Added picture of applying ruleset. Can anyone reproduce the problem? (selecting a random ruleset produces warnings and selecting the same ruleset from within a custom ruleset produces no warnings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce your error with Visual Studio 2017. I don't know exactly what I changed (or if I changed anything at all), but I am able to see the code analysis warning you expect with a custom rule set.

Things I would try:

1. Double check the *Error List* window is visible and not hiding somewhere.
2. Open the rule set file, change the *Action* to *Error* and then back to *Warning* and save it. I wouldn't expect this to be the problem but it's one of the things I did and after which I started seeing the *Error List* window.

[image: Visual Studio 2017 screenshot with the custom rule set working OK]

Comment: Thanks this solves the problem. The .ruleset file must contain each test case explicitly listed which can be achieved by changing the action inside the ruleset editor or by expanding it to see each individual rule.

Comment: Very glad it helped! And sorry it took so long for it to work as expected. In the end, it looks to me that this Visual Studio feature doesn't run very sweetly.